# Showing independence of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I'm working on this exercise at the moment:

> Let $ X: \Omega \rightarrow (0,1) $ be a uniformly distributed random variable. Define $X_n : \Omega \rightarrow (0,1)$ as $$ X_n =\begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } \lfloor2^n X\rfloor \text{ is even}\\
> 1 \text{ if } \lfloor2^n X\rfloor \text{ is odd}.
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ is an independent sequence of Bernoulli$(1/2)$-distributed random variables.

So far I have shown that $X_1,X_2,\dots $ are Bernoulli$(1/2)$-distributed, but I am lacking an approach for showing the independence.